# Login to Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456_Remote access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, vpn

Hello we have been working with a remote Server, but this week I am getting error 18456 with status 1, from SQL Server Management Studio when I try to connect from a remote computer.

We are connecting to the Server through a VPN, but we have the correct ports enabled
as you can see in the `ping` and `telnet` tests:

[ping_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExxwZ.png)

[telnet_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lusZy.png)

So there is no issue with it(as far as we know).

We have tried all the suggestions explained in this page:
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/
(And almost all different blogs/forums found with this error and remote connection errors)

[protocol_properties_ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ghS5.png)

[protocol_properties_ip_tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0puP6.png)
(We also have tried changing to `Yes` **Enabled** property under **IP1** with same results)

**IPALL** seems to be right. (According to recommendations in forums)

[protocol_properties_ip_tab_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDCq1.png)

Remote connections are allowed:

[connection_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aFHG.png)

Security settings are as expected (SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode):

[Security_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXlOB.png)

We have checked all this stuff but we still unable to connect remotely.

SQL Server info:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
    May 14 2014 18:34:29 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

We have been working with the server ok until this week (the server it isn't ours, it is from a customer), we don't know what changed this week, I hope you can give me more ideas to check and solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried logging in with the IP Address?  I mean... on your logon screen, most people enter the computer (server) name. Instead, try entering the IP Address.  If this works, it could indicate a dns problem on the network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but yes actually that´s our comon way to connect to the server.

Comment: If you made any changes to the Protocols in SQL Server Configuration Manager then you need to restart the SQL Server service for those changes to take effect.

Comment: Everything was ok, and after any change we did the service was reloaded.